# Microsoft reporting services trouble with subreport flow

Tags: c#, reporting-services, subreport

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reporting Services 2008 - Long subreports cause page break](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008432/reporting-services-2008-long-subreports-cause-page-break)

I have a subreport in a reporting services main report.  The subreport starts approximately on the middle of the page in the main report.  If i have few detail lines in the subreport so that all can be rendered on page one, everything is ok.  However, if I have more detail lines in the subreport so that it's not possible to print all on page one the entire subreport moves to page two.  I don't want that to happen, how can that be avoided ?

I also noticed that if I have more than one page of data in the subreport, it is also started on page one, and flows like I want.  I want to avoid the situation where I have more lines than can be fitted on page one, and still fewer lines than one page.  I thought the KeepTogether property controlled this, but it's set to false in my report.

Any ideas ?

Comment: same happens here with a table. When there is too much in the table to fit on the first page, but it fits on the second, then the whole table jumps to the second page. The first page of the report then looks veery empty...

Comment: @Svish : It you only have one table than you can pad the subreport with enough blank lines to fill an entire page + 1, then it will move back to the first page and break the table in two.  We however have two subreports in a row, and that strategy won't work, since we want the second subreport to directly follow the first.